# Существительное СПЛИНКЛЕР во множественном числе

Tags: число, словообразование, существительные

Как правильно написать слово *сплинклер* во множественном числе? Сплинклера или сплинклеры?

Comment: @evg, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы про  - ороситель, то
спри́нклер,

спри́нклеры,

спри́нклеров,

спри́нклерам,

спри́нклерами,

спри́нклерах
(Источник: «Полная акцентуированная парадигма по А. А. Зализняку»)

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_forms/69925